# Why does this create an error - a ghost NSArray?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

When I enable (uncomment) this line of code I get a SIGABRT crash - which is strange, to me, because I have never had this issue before.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
```

The error I get is:

> 2011-12-28 14:03:00.118 MapWithTableModalView-001[2006:11603] Localized name database is not present
>   2011-12-28 14:03:01.110 MapWithTableModalView-001[2006:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

The project produces no errors or warnings.

The project is based on 2 UIViewControllers that slide on top of each other via a button - ModalViewContoller. When I press the button, the crash happens.

Just adding the code here - it is part of a tutorial, but I still want to get it:-) I know this does not look like an ordinary array, but the data is set like this in the project. Once I figure this out I want to set it in a Plist.

```
-(void)loadOurAnnotations
    {
CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;


    #pragma mark - Apple Stores
workingCoordinate.latitude = 51.514298;
workingCoordinate.longitude = -73.973034;
iCodeBlogAnnotation *appleStore1 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc]     initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [appleStore1 setTitle:@"Apple Store 5th Ave."];
[appleStore1 setSubtitle:@"Apple's Flagship Store"];
[appleStore1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeApple];

[viewController.mapView addAnnotation:appleStore1];

workingCoordinate.latitude = 51.514298;
workingCoordinate.longitude = -0.141949;
iCodeBlogAnnotation *appleStore2 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
[appleStore2 setTitle:@"Apple Store St. Regent"];
[appleStore2 setSubtitle:@"London England"];
[appleStore2 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeApple];

[viewController.mapView addAnnotation:appleStore2];



     }
```

If you would like me to post any additional code, I would be happy to, but I am not sure where to look anymore and hence don't really know which bit to post to be helpful.

-Jeff

Comment: This `-loadOurAnnotations` method doesn't actually ever set your view controller's annotations array (or add these annotations to it). That's why it's empty. You need to either add them to that array or get the array from the map view (see answer below).

Comment: Yeah the idea is that I am trying to split them into 2 different ViewControllers - so that I can show more Map and more Table View. Looks they are more integrated then I thought:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your annotations array is empty (has zero elements).

Looking at your `-loadOurAnnotations` method, you never actually seem to set the `annotations` array that you're reading. Try updating that line to something like below and see if that helps:

```
// I'm not sure where viewController comes from but I'll assume it's a method on this
// class and that it's the same class that defines -loadOurAnnotations. If it's not,
// update this appropriately to get access to the mapView to which you've added
// the annotations
cell.textLabel.text = [[[[viewController mapView] annotations] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
```

Comment: In the same file in a -(void)loadOurAnnotations as the cell.text....
it has 2 elements in it atm, for testing - will get more later.

Comment: @jwk82 Can you edit your question and add that method's implementation?

Comment: Cool - thanks for the advice, it didn't really fix it, but i'll have another look - puzzling it through:-)